# PostgreSQL - "stack depth limit exceeded" when insert into partitioned table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a table with partition:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_data(
  id uuid default uuid_generate_v4() not null,
  name text,
  created_date date not null,
  constraint "some_data_pk" primary key (id, created_data)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (created_date);

--! Partition table
CREATE TABLE some_data_2023 PARTITION OF some_data FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-01-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-01-01 00:00:00');

--! Index
CREATE INDEX some_data_idx ON some_data(name);

--!Trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_some_data_partitions()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.created_date >= DATE '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND NEW.created_date < DATE '2024-01-01 00:00:00') THEN
        INSERT INTO some_data_2023 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'No partition found for created_date %', NEW.created_date;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER some_data_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON some_data
    FOR EACH row
    EXECUTE FUNCTION update_some_data_partitions();
```

Then, I created simple `insert` script:

```
INSERT INTO some_data(id, name, created_date)
VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), 'name', '2023-05-08 12:00:00');
```

But I got an error when I ran it:

```
ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded. Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth"...
```

On adding to partitioned table.

I think it's something wrong with my `trigger` function, but I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me?

Comment: oh yes, there is something wrong, with every row you enter you enter another row and then you tirgger the trigger over and over again, what exactly do you try to achieve, the partioning would automatically insert the data inthe correct partition no need to do it yourself, but you shluld have a 2023 table in the first place

Comment: Hm, so how I should fix my code?

Comment: reverse the trigger chech if something is outside the date range raise an error and no else

Comment: It is very similar code as in docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html I do not get how I should fix it. Can you provide code example?

Comment: but you could also add a check constraint for such simple logic

Comment: see https://dbfiddle.uk/BDu3G1tp

Comment: Oh, that reverse. Thank you so much. I would never find out it.

Comment: Best is to have no trigger at all. You'll get an error anyway if there is no matching partition.

Comment: I know, but I will extend it with next partitions. Do you have any idea how to do it without trigger? But also to update partitions when new row is added to main table?

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks like you built this based on [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-OVERVIEW), but mixed declarative partitioning with inheritance-based approach. Declarative partioning doesn't require triggers to route your queries to the right partition - it happens automatically based on your partition range spec:

   ```sql
   ...FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-01-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-01-01 00:00:00')`
   ```

   As [@nbk immediately pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76199075/postgresql-stack-depth-limit-exceeded-when-insert-into-partitioned-table#comment134376518_76199075), adding the trigger on top of declarative partitioning duplicates this routing mechanism, so each record ends up duplicating itself recursively, until it hits the `max_stack_depth` limit. To fix that, just remove the trigger.

   A side-note on that trigger: it handles `insert`, but `delete`, `update`, `merge` and `truncate` would be left unhandled. A [conditional](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) block checking [`TG_OP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) can solve that. That's just a side-note on trigger construction - you don't need one for routing to partitions, and you also don't need it to raise the exception when you're missing a matching partition: that's built-in, default behaviour.
2. Since PostgreSQL 13, you no longer need [`uuid-ossp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) to generate uuid v4 - you can use built-in [`gen_random_uuid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html).
3. If you're trying to automate partition management, you can look into [`pg_partman` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/pg_partman-470-released-2495/).
4. If you prefer automating it yourself, you can run your check in the trigger, create and attach the new period's partition when you get a record that doesn't match any of the existing periods.

   Keep in mind the trigger slows down all inserts on the table, so it might be a better idea to accept those into a default partition, then periodically check for groups and once the catch-all caught enough records from the same period, give them their own partition.

   Or build a new-year's partition at the end of the year, if they're coming in pretty much sequentially.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So how shouldI fix the trigger to catch also deletes and updates? Also if I remove this trigger it should works correctly? When I put smth to main table, all partitions will be updated as well?

Comment: I see. If I remove trigger it works fine also

Comment: That's right, it's meant to function without the trigger. The "main" table works more like a view that aggregates all the partitions, which are the actual tables holding data. In general, when you need a trigger that has to process all traffic on a table, you can either build one for each type of event, or just two: one `TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON...` that internally handles `insert`, `update`, `delete` based on the value of [`TG_OP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) and a separate one that just handles `truncate`.

Comment: Hm, I've already removed trigger and it looks like it works fine when I put/delete or update data in "main" table. All other partitions are correctly updated. So imo I do not need this trigger anymore, because it works well.

Comment: Correct. When you do something to the "main", postgres checks which partitions should be affected by comparing your query structure to each partition's range and automatically chooses which ones it should interact with: which one to delete a record from, which one to insert a new one into, which records to update where, which ones to fetch rows from.